# How to iterate with result of previous rows of same column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numba, vaex

Starting from a Data Frame with the columns A B D P:

```
import numba
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import vaex

d = {'A':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],'B':[30,35,32,35,31,39,37],'D':[12,10,13,19,12,21,13],'P':[3,3,3,3,3,3,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['C'] = 0

df
```

Exporting to hdf5:

```
df.to_csv("v_df", index=False)
    
df = vaex.from_csv("v_df", convert=True, chunk_size=5_000_000)
```

I need to calculate the column 'C' with each row with a desired result as follow:

```
'C': [0, 1.666666667, 0.552380952, 2.333630952, 0.962202381, 6.38155722, 5.714890553]
```

To reach this result I need to iterate each row starting on row (1) and calculate something like:

```
%%time
@numba.njit
def func(B, D, C, b_0=0):
    n = len(B)
    b = np.full(n, b_0, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(1, n):
        b[i] = ((((B[i] - B[i - 1]) / B[i - 1])) * D[i]) + C[i-1]
    return b
df['C'] = func(df['B'].to_numpy(),df['D'].to_numpy(),df['C'].to_numpy())
df
```

But it doesn't work.

It results ok for the first and second row:

```
'C': [0, 1.666666667, -1.114286, 1.781250, -1.371429, 5.419355, -0.666667]
```

I've tried the 'shift' (suggestion by sammywemmy). It works ok for this example data frame before 'vaex.from_csv', but when implemented the concept to the big data frame via vaex, shift is not working.

So, the question is: Is there a 'good practice' way to perform this calculus (iterate the result of a row in column 'C' considering the previous rows in 'C') with a large data source (I´m using vaex to import from a 1 million rows csv)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this : ``df.B.shift(-1).sub(df.B).div(df.B).mul(df.D.shift(-1)).cumsum().shift(fill_value=0)``

Comment: sammywemmy, thanks for your fast answer and help... It works perfect for my example createad with a simple pandas data frame! Thanks! But... when I try to implement the concept to the big data frame from vaex, it is not working. Shows the message: 'AttributeError: 'Expression' object has no attribute 'shift''. Thanks for yout help...

Comment: I am not familiar with vaex; you could have a look at their API and see if there is alternative to `shift`

Comment: Once again, I would like to thank you for your help and kindness. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure it is the optimal solution but at least it is working: you can use the [apply](https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#vaex.dataframe.DataFrame.apply) method with `vectorize` set to `True`.

Here is the full snippet:

```py
import numba
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import vaex

d = {'A':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],'B':[30,35,32,35,31,39,37],'D':[12,10,13,19,12,21,13],'P':[3,3,3,3,3,3,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['C'] = 0

df

# I removed the b_0 for simplicity
def my_func(B, D, C):
    n = len(B)
    b = np.full(n, 0, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(1, n):
        b[i] = ((((B[i] - B[i - 1]) / B[i - 1])) * D[i]) + C[i-1]

    return b

df_vaex = vaex.from_pandas(df)

df_vaex.apply(my_func, arguments=[df_vaex["B"], df_vaex["D"], df_vaex["C"]], vectorize=True)
```

It gives the expected output:

```
0          0
1    1.66667
2   -1.11429
3    1.78125
4   -1.37143
5    5.41935
6  -0.666667
```

---

Basically, `apply` method allows to apply functions row by row and if you set `vectorize` to `True` the full arrays will be passed instead of the row values. In your case it is mandatory since you need the values from the previous rows to compute the C value in a given row.

Comment: Perfect! I am very happy to achieve results without need of 'shift' and to learn a bit more! Thank you very much!

Comment: Perfect! Another suggestion is to implement the shift method for vaex, here you can fin the answer related to this task: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61075267/8056572

Comment: Hi, I tried to understand your solution, and I think I am lost? At no moment in the code you have posted you store result in column 'C'. So how/when in the calculation the result from the previous row 'C[i-1]' is retrieved to be used in the next row 'C[i]'? Thanks for clarifying.